# mysql/RoR database design

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

Is it ok for a table to have two of the same foreign keys as columns?

I.e. I have two tables, one is Country, the other is City. In the Country table:

COUNTRY
    --------------
id
name
capitalcity <--- this would have foreign key 'city_id'.
populouscity <-- this would also have a foreign key 'city_id'. 
created_at 
updated_at

CITY
    -------
id
name
populous (bool)
capital (bool)
created_at
updated_at

Keep in mind that the capital city may or may not also be the most populous.
I have wondered if I should just seperate out the two boolean colums of city, have city as city with name only, and have a populous table that references to city, and capital that references to city too. And have two seperate foreign keys in the countries table from the two new tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about the design this way

```
COUNTRY
--------------
id
name    

CITY
-------
id
country_id   ( useful to know what country a city is in  )
name
created_at
updated_at

CAPITALS
----------
id
city_id         Unique

POPULUS
-------
id
city_id         Unique
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It seems I forgot to think the other way... that cities can belong to countries. D'oh!

Comment: @DeiS This design does not model your requirements (as currently stated in your question). For example, there is nothing to prevent a country from having multiple capitals or multiple "most populous" cities. The `country_id` could be put in CAPITALS and POPULOUS (as before the edit), but this still allows a city to be the capital of a country it does not belong to, _unless_ you use identifying relationship, but then this design starts to approach what I have [proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17077227/533120).

Comment: Ok, i get what you're saying. I need to think this through. It's getting weird. Here is the grand idea for this portion of my design: Countries will be identified by their ISO3166-2 codes, then I'll have states, maybe down to three levels unerneath countries, each country should have one capital, one populous city, and then each state could have the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's OK. People sometimes avoid such "explicit" FKs because they are not "flexible", but if you *know* you'll always need to relate to exactly these two cities, this is the appropriate design. In any case, you don't need these FKs *and* bool flags.

What I don't see is how you connect non-capital and not-most-populous cities to the country. If you're not careful about how you design your keys, you could end-up with the situation where a city can be a capital of the country it does not belong to.

Using an identifying relationship avoids this issue:

[image]

So, every city is identified by a number (CITY_NO) *within* its country. When the PK is migrated back from CITY to COUNTRY, the COUNTRY_ID is "merged" back to its origin, so there cannot be a country mismatch (note FK1 and FK2 on COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID).

CAPITAL_NO and POPULOUS_NO are left NULL-able so they can temporarily remain NULL to solve the chicken-and-egg problem caused by circular FKs. This works because InnoDB enforces FKs using [MATCH SIMPLE](http://wiki.burnsoft.net/KB58.ashx) method, so it is enough for just one component of the composite FK to be NULL to avoid FK violation.

BTW, consider whether you actually need POPULOUS_ID - if you keep the population of all cities, then you can derive which one is most populous simply by finding MAX.

You can always add a surrogate key such as CITY_ID if you need it for child FKs or to pacify your ORM...

Comment: I think this is a good answer, although I need to read it a few times to understand the logic. Believe it or not, I did do db design up to 5th nf in college (over 10 years ago).
When actually modelling specific needs it can get quite messy.
Thanks

Comment: I should also point out that I'm using RubyOnRails to do all the database modeling relationships for me, when I work the design all out I will mirror the relationships on the database side and reduce the lengths of columns.
The penultimate paragraph is also food for thought, my idea is to populate a db with specific cities, i.e most populated, and/or capitals, for the US as country, these would be new york and washington dc respectively, but for the uk, it would London for both. Thanks